# Count BigQuery event.params based on event.key

Tags: sql, firebase-realtime-database, google-bigquery

I am attempting to count the events filtering on their parameter.

For example, suppose that I have the following. Here's the real one for the inquisitive minds out there.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/MUzcR.png

```
event_date | event_timestamp | event_name | event_params.key | event_params.value.string_value
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
some_date  | some_timestamp  | some_name  | some_key_1       | some_string_1
                                          | some_key_2       | some_string_2
                                          | some_key_3       | some_string_3
                                          | some_key_4       | some_string_4
```

event_params.key and event_params.value is an array of values. I need to filter out anything in that array that doesn't match my key. In addition, I need to count each occurrence of a specific string value. I attempted to do something like the following:

```
 SELECT DISTINCT event_name,
(SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST(event_params)
  WHERE key = 'relationship_lenght') AS Length,
(SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST(event_params)
  WHERE key = 'relationship_location') AS Location,
(SELECT value.string_value FROM UNNEST(event_params)
  WHERE key = 'relationship_gender') AS Gender

FROM `stormbreaker-studios.analytics_243434300.events_20200902`

WHERE 
  event_name = 'relationship_created_gender' OR
  event_name = 'relationship_created_location' OR
  event_name = 'relationship_created_interests'

LIMIT 10
```

It returns `null` for all columns. What I'm expecting to get would be something along the lines of this, horizontal or vertical, makes no difference.

#### Expected Output

```
Male | Female | Trans | Non-Binary | New York | San Antonio | 1-5mo | 5-10mo |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
10   |   11   |   1   |     3      |     3    |      17     |   1   |    61  |
```

Each `Count` per column is derived from the value associated with `some_key` in the above example. The value is static, from a list that is known. For example, the value for `relationship_gender` could be `Male`, `Female`, etc.. and I'd compare to match that.

Comment: Your sample data doesn't have any of the strings you are looking for so there is no surprise that nothing is found.  You also have the same strings used for the `key` and for the `event_name`, which looks suspicious.

Comment: I'm looking to count the value for the key `relationship_created...` The key is always the same. Am I using unnest incorrectly?

Comment: I feel like you are mixing `event_name` with `event_params.key` which prevents us from helping you. Please double check wording in your question and correct/clarify it. Simplified data example and expected output will also help a lot  -  [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant I've updated the question. You were correct, I accidentally forgot to change the keys when moving it over to Stack Overflow. It's been corrected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would generally structure your query like this:

```
with temp as (
  select * from `project.dataset.table`
  left join unnest(event_params) ep
  where event_name in('relationship_created_gender',
                      'relationship_created_location',
                      'relationship_created_interests')
),
logic as(
  select
    case when key = 'relationship_gender' and value.string_value = 'Male' then 1 else 0 end as gender_male,
    case when key = 'relationship_gender' and value.string_value = 'Female' then 1 else 0 end as gender_female,
    ... etc
    case when key = 'relationship_location' and value._value = 'New York' then 1 else 0 end as location_ny,
    ... etc
  from temp
)
select
  sum(gender_male) as Male,
  sum(gender_female) as Female,
  ...etc
from logic
```

You might have to make some adjustments based on if the things you want to count are in the `string_value` or `int_value` format.  If you have a unique `event_id`, I would `count distinct` that instead of summing `1`s.

Comment: This may work! Wow, that's really concise. I'll get back to you if this works out for me.

Answer (score 1):

I really recommend you to adjust your output requirements and have below output format

```
key                         value         cnt
relationship_gender         Male          10
relationship_gender         Female        11
relationship_gender         Trans         1
relationship_gender         Non-Binary    3
relationship_location       New York      3
relationship_location       San Antonio   17
relationship_lenght         1-5mo         1
relationship_lenght         5-10mo        61
```

above format much more flexible for any further processing (including pivoting if you still need it that way)

So, if above is acceptable for you  - below is the query for it

```
#standardSQL
SELECT key, value.string_value AS value, COUNT(1) cnt
FROM `stormbreaker-studios.analytics_243434300.events_20200902` t,
UNNEST(event_params) 
WHERE STARTS_WITH(LOWER(event_name), 'relationship_created_')
AND STARTS_WITH(LOWER(key), 'relationship_')
GROUP BY key, value
```

As I mentioned - if you still need it - you can easily add pivoting here - there are multiple related posts including answered by myself ...

Comment: Thanks for this response. +1 unfortunately doing it this way actually doesn't work, for my use,  in retrospect. I have some values that are variadic strings, which I didn't notice at first. However, this is very useful for other things and is a great answer.